# Unable to allocate new pages in table space "XXX" IBM DB2 SQL Replication

Tags: sql, database, db2, database-replication, db2-luw

Product: **IBM DB2**

OS: **Windows 2008 R2**

I am trying to perform **SQL replication** on my database, I have created the capture tables, while I am trying to register the tables I got the following error message

> **[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0289N**  Unable to allocate new  pages in table space "xxxxxxx".  SQLSTATE=57011"

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but "unable to allocate new pages" means either there's no space on disk to extend the tablespace or the tablespace is full and autoextend is turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to check the extent size of your tablespace. Run the following command `SELECT TBSPACE, OWNER, EXTENTSIZE FROM SYSCAT.TABLESPACES` This will give details of `EXTENTSIZE` of `TABLESPACE`. You may need to change the extent size depending on your requirements.

An extent is a block of storage within a table space container. It represents the number of pages of data that will be written to a container before writing to the next container. When you create a table space, you can choose the extent size based on your requirements for performance and storage management. See more details [**here**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0004964.html)